# Why is my .infobox not resizing to parent as I zoom in or out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've been trying to create this news slider kind of thing in combination with JQuery. I'm not concerned about getting the interactions working, but my infobox, which is a div, that contains the "Prev" and "Next" anchor tags is not resizing to fit the total width of its parent div. I've tried to fix the parent width and tried to give the child div a max-width of 100%. This only resized the div to the length of the text inside my infobox. I'm just a newbie at this, so I must've done a whole lot wrong in the CSS.

---

Here's my code! Might come in handy if you're willing to help me:

```
<body>

    <img class="start" src="stb-logo.png">

    <div id="index">
        <h3 align="center">Nieuws</h3>    
            <div id="ticker">
                <img src="no-image-available.jpg">
                <img src="no-image-available.jpg">
                <img src="no-image-available.jpg">
                <img src="no-image-available.jpg">
            </div>
        <div class="infobox">
            <div>Some text to describe the image</div>
            <a id="prev2" href="#">Prev</a>
            <a id="next2" href="#">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <article>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut risus lectus, vestibulum et euismod vel, aliquet in dolor. Aliquam blandit, dolor eget rhoncus vestibulum, enim metus convallis quam, nec commodo arcu mauris eget quam. Aliquam aliquam mollis condimentum. Fusce pretium tortor augue. Sed erat enim, congue sit amet congue sit amet, adipiscing quis metus. Nulla et elit quis dolor malesuada tincidunt.Vivamus ultricies lectus auctor dui condimentum ut luctus nunc scelerisque. Etiam semper tristique orci, sit amet suscipit purus eleifend ullamcorper. Etiam ullamcorper pretium varius. Aliquam quis urna metus.
    </article>

</body>
```

---

Here's my CSS!

```
body{
    font-family: Verdana;
}

header.nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

img.start{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    background-color: grey;
}

div#index{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    clear: inherit;
}

div#ticker{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div#ticker img{
    z-index: -1;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.infobox{
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 80;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.infobox > div{
    max-width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I have! [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FFakkel/22s6r/2/) it is! Just don't know if I did it right. What I forgot to mention is that I used Mike Alsup's cycle plugin for JQuery. It might be because of that that it's not showing this single img I'm trying to display by hiding the other as they overflow the div. Instead it displays every one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute positioned divs will not adjust to the parent size, as long as you don't set the start- and end positions, like `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom`.

Try the following CSS for your case:

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size:10px;
}

header.nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

img.start {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
}

div#index {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;   
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  clear: inherit;
}

div#ticker {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
}

div#ticker img {
  z-index: -1;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
 }

.infobox {
  bottom: 0;    
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  }

.infobox #prev2 {
 float:left;
 display:block;
}
.infobox #prev2 {
 float:right;
 text-align:right;
 display:block;
}

.infobox > div{
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  }

article {
 clear:both;
  }
```

or alternatively you can drop the display:absolute, and use the following css for the infobox:

```
.infobox{
  bottom: 0;    
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  float:left;    
}
```

**Edit:** fixed zooming issue

Comment: I had preference over the alternative as it actualy centered and stayed at this position whenever I try zooming. My idea was that the infobox with that slight opacity would be placed over the width of the img. Would I still be able to achieve this without the position property?

Comment: Fariz, have a look at this [working example](http://indepenmedia.nl/fariz/), based on your fiddle.

Comment: Holy dung, that is awesome! What'd you do? What should I change about the way I go about my code? I want to get better, so please tell me!

Comment: Use a `max-width` and `position:relative` on `#index`, then apply a `bottom:0` and `width:100%` on `.infobox`.

Comment: You've helped alot! Dank je!

Comment: Kinda' new here. Was waiting for a reaction for some time, and because of that I thought accepting the answer would lock the page from people trying to place further comments.